# Print all permutations containing exactly k elements

Tags: algorithm, permutation

In *Wolfram Mathematica*, writing:

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, d}]
```

or writing:

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {4}]
```

I get:

```
{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, d, c}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {a, d, b, c}, {a, d, c, b}, 
 {b, a, c, d}, {b, a, d, c}, {b, c, a, d}, {b, c, d, a}, {b, d, a, c}, {b, d, c, a}, 
 {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, b, a, d}, {c, b, d, a}, {c, d, a, b}, {c, d, b, a}, 
 {d, a, b, c}, {d, a, c, b}, {d, b, a, c}, {d, b, c, a}, {d, c, a, b}, {d, c, b, a}}
```

After much effort and precious aid had here in the forum, trying to "translate" [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm), I was able to duplicate this function using the following code:

```
permutations[A_] := Module[{},
  n = Length[A];
  U = A;
  V = ConstantArray[0, n];
  B = ConstantArray[0, {n!, n}];
  B = ReplacePart[B, 1 -> U];
  h = 0;
  i = 0;
  j = 2;
  While[i < n,
     If[V[[i + 1]] < i,
        If[Mod[i, 2] == 0,
           U = ReplacePart[U, {1 -> U[[i + 1]], i + 1 -> U[[1]]}],       
           U = ReplacePart[U, {i + 1 -> U[[V[[i + 1]] + 1]], V[[i + 1]] + 1 -> U[[i + 1]]}]
       ];
       For[k = 1, k <= j - 1, k++, If[Norm[B[[k]] - U] == 0, h = 1]];
       If[h == 0, B = ReplacePart[B, j -> U]; j = j + 1, h = 0];
       V[[i + 1]] = V[[i + 1]] + 1; i = 0,
       V[[i + 1]] = 0; i = i + 1
    ];
  ]; 
  B = Sort[DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[B], {0 ..}, Infinity]]; Return[B]]
```

On the other hand, writing:

```
Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {3}]
```

I get:

```
{{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, b}, {a, c, d}, {a, d, b}, {a, d, c}, {b, a, c}, {b, a, d},
 {b, c, a}, {b, c, d}, {b, d, a}, {b, d, c}, {c, a, b}, {c, a, d}, {c, b, a}, {c, b, d},
 {c, d, a}, {c, d, b}, {d, a, b}, {d, a, c}, {d, b, a}, {d, b, c}, {d, c, a}, {d, c, b}}
```

and in this case I do not know where to turn. You know you indicate some this algorithm in the literature also to be able to duplicate that other functionality? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `Union @@ permutations /@ Subsets[{a, b, c, d}, {3}]` produces the output you want I think this question could be reduced simply to how to implement a k-Subsets function in top-level code.

Fortunately that has been included in *Mathematica* for years in the [Combinatorica package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/tutorial/Combinatorica.html).

To see the code you may use:

```
Quiet @ Get["Combinatorica`"]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions @ KSubsets
```

Since the package is also freely available from:

- http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~sriram/Combinatorica/index.html

I shall reproduce that portion of the code here.

```
KSubsets[l_List,0] := { {} }
KSubsets[l_List,1] := Partition[l,1]
KSubsets[l_List,2] := Flatten[Table[{l[[i]], l[[j]]}, 
                                    {i, Length[l]-1}, 
                                    {j, i+1, Length[l]}
                              ], 
                              1
                      ]
KSubsets[l_List,k_Integer?Positive] := {l} /; (k == Length[l])
KSubsets[l_List,k_Integer?Positive] := {}  /; (k > Length[l])

KSubsets[s_List, k_Integer] := Prepend[Map[s[[#]] &, KS[Length[s], k]], s[[Range[k] ]] ]

KS = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, 
             Module[{h, ss = Range[k], x},  
                    Table[(h = Length[ss]; x = n;
                           While[x === ss[[h]], h--; x--];
                           ss = Join[Take[ss, h - 1], 
                                     Range[ss[[h]]+1, ss[[h]]+Length[ss]-h+1] 
                                ]), 
                          {Binomial[n, k]-1}
                    ] 
             ]
     ]
```

Comment: @Manu Why do you not try translating `KS` into whatever language you need?  While you may need to replace e.g. `Table` and `Range` with explicit iterators I see nothing in this code that requires a high-level language.